# Privileged access is not working via API data showing null

Tags: azure, powershell, graph, roles, pim

I have a user with owner permission on subscription and I am trying to use

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/privilegedAccess/azureResources/resources
```

the result is always null for a subscription. I have the privileged access permission for the user I am working with.

Result

```
@odata.context                                                 value
--------------                                                 -----
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#governanceResources {}
```

Update: When I try to assign owner on a RG  am able to fetch result

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the role for the user in `Privileged Identity Management` in the portal, make sure the `Status` of the assignment is `Active`, if it is `Eligible`, please update it to `Active`, otherwise the `Owner` role will not take effect, it will return null.

[image]

You could check it in the `Privileged Identity Management` ->  `Azure resources` -> select your subscription -> `Assignments` -> search for your user account.

[image]

Another way, you could navigate to the subscription in the portal directly -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> `Add role assignment` -> search for your user account and add it as `Owner`, it will also work. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).

[image]

Comment: I am using a delegated user which have the permission and owner permission on resource group returns results. while assigning the permission on subscription does not

Comment: @displayuser Did you follow my reply to have a check?

Comment: I tried doing the same and manually assigning owner permission as well but still I am not getting the result.

Comment: @displayuser I could not reproduce your issue, all work fine on my side.